# How do I add an HttpSessionListener to Camel's embedded Jetty

Tags: apache-camel, embedded-jetty

To set an HttpSessionListener to Camel's embedded Jetty while using Rest I have tries this:

```java
SessionHandler sess = new SessionHandler();
sess.addEventListener(new HttpSessionListener() {
    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        // some code
        se.getSession().setAttribute("WasHere", true);
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        // some cleanup code that really can't be palced anywhere else
    }
});
String sessionHandlerString = "jettySessionHandler";
_integration.getRegistry().put(sessionHandlerString, sess); // this works

String port = _properties.getProperty("port");

RestConfiguration restConfiguration = new RestConfiguration();
restConfiguration.setComponent("jetty");
HashMap<String, Object> options = new HashMap<>();
options.put("sessionSupport", true);
options.put("handlers", sessionHandlerString);
restConfiguration.setEndpointProperties(options);
restConfiguration.setHost("localhost");
restConfiguration.setPort(Integer.parseInt(port));
restConfiguration.setBindingMode(RestConfiguration.RestBindingMode.auto);
_integration.getContext().setRestConfiguration(restConfiguration);

// getting an object
JettyHttpComponent9 jettyComponent = _integration.getContext().getComponent("jetty", JettyHttpComponent9.class);

RouteBuilder rb = new RouteBuilder(_integration.getContext()) {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        rest("/test/path")
            .get().route().process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    HttpMessage msg = exchange.getIn(HttpMessage.class);
                    Object ret = msg.getRequest().getSession().getAttribute("WasHere");
                    msg.setBody("Been there or not? - " + ret);
                }
            });
    }
};
```

This returns "Been there or not? - null", so the session listener didn't work.

Rest config makes a Jetty component route and does add the `handlers` option. Diving down with the debugger I had an impression that my handler was added to the Jetty endpoint call way too late, when the session had been already started, so it didn't have any effect.

How do I add my own `HttpSessionListener` to the embedded Jetty server in Camel? The API doesn't seem to provide me access to the Jetty's `Server` and other objects despite the component being called "jetty" and it looks normal not to be so abstract of the Jetty's internals.

The main goal is to run something in the session destroy event.

*update* - tried to hack it and add a session listener in a processor - `IllegalStateException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

future Camel Jetty user.

If you want to use your own `HttpSessionListener` or, in broader sense, Jetty's `SessionHandler`, just never set `sessionSupport=true`. It replaces your `SessionHandler` with an empty one that does **nothing**.

Then add your handler to the endpoint uri as you would normally do: `?handlers=yourSessionHandlerBeanRef`.

In the example above, just comment out this line:

```
//options.put("sessionSupport", true);
```

Hope I've saved you a day or two.

Comment: The editor ate up my greetings. The post starts with the "Hello, " substring. But I am angry that I lost two days on this problem. I need to express my passive-aggressiveness

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a standard Servlet or Filter to your camel instance?

If so, make the `init()` add the `HttpSessionListener` to the `ServletContext` and the implementation of said servlet/filter be a no-op.

It's important to add the listener this during the `init()` as that's the only time its allowed to be done (during the startup/init of a WebApp).

Comment: I'm not sure I can, will have to investigate it or ask how to do it

Comment: No, unfortunately I haven't found out how to add a servlet to the jetty servlet context before the service starts, otherwise again the state is illegal when I'm adding anything as a context listener